# gcc-7: g++-7: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, darkflow

I am running setup.py to compile darkflow.
When i run the command `yum install gcc-python3-plugin`
, i always hit into the following errors, i have gcc & g++-7 installed

**Error**

```
running build_ext building 'darkflow.cython_utils.nms' extension gcc-7 CXX=g++-7 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g
-fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-EKG1lX/python3.6-3.6.5=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c darkflow/cython_utils/nms.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/darkflow/cython_utils/nms.o gcc-7: error: CXX=g++-7: No such file or directory error: command 'gcc-7' failed with exit status 1
```

***When i run my python***

```
ubuntu@host1 # python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Anyone know what causes the error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late answer, but maybe this could help someone

`gcc-7` and `g++-7` are different things. GCC is a collection of compilers ([GNU Compiler Collection](https://www.freelancinggig.com/blog/2017/11/10/difference-gcc-g/)), while `g++` is a compiler for c++, it is included in `gcc`.
You say you have installed `gcc` and `g++-7`, but error says that it couldn't find `gcc-7` so try to install `gcc-7`.